# Изменение строк в файле

Tags: bash

Создали файл script.txt. Файл содержит команды на выполнение, следующего вида 
<команда> [параметры]. Необходимо внести изменения, чтоб получить измененный файл, следующего вида <команда> [параметры].xml [параметры]
Пошел следующим образом

- `name_file= grep -E -o "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)" $HOME/SEARCH/OUT/script.txt #поиск IP-адреса в строке`
- `sed -i -e 's:nmap :nmap -oX '$HOME/SEARCH/OUT/script/$namefile.xml' :' /$HOME/SEARCH/OUT/script.txt # делаю замену в строке`

В результате получаю следующую строку после изменений nmap -oX $HOME/SEARCH/OUT/script/.xml 192.168.1.1. Подскажите что делаю не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
   #!/bin/bash

cat script.txt | while read f; do 
    nf=`echo {$f} | grep -E -o "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?).(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"` 
    echo $f | sed -e s/"nmap $nf"/"nmap -oX $nf.xml $nf"/ >> out.txt
done
mv out.txt script.txt
```

А вообще - есть такая проблема, что sed не принимает переменные из bash-скрипта. В интернетах об этом пишут:

http://nixcraft.com/showthread.php/14372-sed-bash-variable

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584894/sed-scripting-environment-variable-substitution

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/sed-doesn%27t-accept-$variable-in-bash-script-325935/